# What's the criterion for FileEntry restoration in FileSystem API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to load files and the restoration seems to work fine at first but they become unrestorable after app reload/browser restart etc. So is there any way to make the restoration possible for longer than single browser session? And there are no docs for restoration. Just the api reference which doesn't explain jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-retainEntry)

> If the app has the 'retainEntries' permission under 'fileSystem', entries are retained indefinitely. Otherwise, entries are retained only while the app is running and across restarts.

Comment: That's about `retainEntry` function, which is different and is used to get the id of the file, I think.

Comment: Then clarify your question. Preferably with a code sample. But in any case, this answers how to make entry ids restorable across sessions.

Comment: Ah wait, that's an unfortunate name clash. It works. The permission and the function have same name but the permission is for the other function (`restoreEntry`). Which caused the confusion. Thanks!

Comment: Well, _technically_ the permission is for `retainEntry`, since the fact that it is a long-lived id is probably set there.